# Making it easier to access hidden comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

This is a follow-up of this [recent post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1576/comments-that-are-not-displayed-right-away-add-see-10-other-comments/1577), and hopefully a feasible suggestion.

**Problem:** If a question/answer has many comments (say more than fit on my screen) and I decide to read them all, in order to be able to read them in order without missing half of them, it is necessary to scroll at first somewhat down to find the line “add/see 10 other comments” and then up again, because the hiding doesn't follow the chronological order.

**Suggested solution:** Instead of that line at the end, there could be a clickable line just *before* the comments saying something like "Some comments are hidden. Click to show all 17 comments". Several "commentable" web sites handle it like that, and that would avoid useless scrolling or the frustration of reading a comment which is a reaction/reply to something in a preceding comment that is not visible.

Comment: This is the sort of suggestion that should be done at the level of all SE.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar while one could post this to meta.SO it is my understanding that sites' metas are also and appropriate place for such general suggestions. For example see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/192/minor-edits-subject-to-review

Comment: We're working on comment visibility _in general_, since it's not optimal, however this is an interesting idea. I'm going to pass it along to the folks that are looking into ways to improve the comment system. If implemented, though, it would be part of a larger change - I just want to let you know we saw this.

Comment: @TimPost thank you folks! Good to know.